Failed to create usercontrol
I got this msg while try to use usercontrol with visual studio 2022
X

Failed to create component 'CtrPersonCard The error

message follows

'System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'DVLDNew.CtrPersonCard' not found.

at System.Runtime Type.CreateInstancelmpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr. Binder binder Object[] as, Cultureinfo culture Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

at System.Activator CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture,

Object[] activationAttributes)

at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr. Binder binder Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)

at

System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignSurface.CreateInstanc e(Type type)

at

Microsoft VisualStudio. Design. VSDesignSurface.CreateInstance( Type type)

at

System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost System.Compo nentModel.Design. IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type component Type, String name)

at

System.Drawing.Design.Toolboxitem.CreateComponentsCore(1 DesignerHost host)

at

System.Drawing.Design. Toolboxltem.CreateComponentsCore(1 DesignerHost host, IDictionar

Trying making user control c#
But i got this msg while try to use it
I can see control in tool box but got above msg
Please help

This exception indicates that the constructor for the CtrPersonCard class is not being found

Check if your user control class has the constructor.
like this:
public CtrPersonCard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

If the constructor is present, then maybe you are calling another usercontrol or the namespace is wrong on your code...

It looks like you're encountering a System.MissingMethodException when trying to create an instance of the CtrPersonCard component in your application.
This exception indicates that the constructor for the CtrPersonCard class is not being found.
public class CtrPersonCard
{
    // Ensure there's a public parameterless constructor
    public CtrPersonCard()
    {
        // Initialization code
    }
}

